# Wrap audio data of the pcm_alaw type into an MKA audio file using the ffmpeg API

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, encoder

Imagine that in my project, I receive `RTP` packets with the payload [type-8](http://www.networksorcery.com/enp/protocol/rtp.htm), for later saving this load as the Nth part of the audio track. I extract this load from the `RTP` packet and save it to a temporary buffer:

```cpp
...

while ((rtp = receiveRtpPackets()).withoutErrors()) {
   payloadData.push(rtp.getPayloadData());
}

audioGenerator.setPayloadData(payloadData);
audioGenerator.recordToFile();

...
```

After filling a temporary buffer of a certain size with this payload, I process this buffer, namely, extract the entire payload and encode it using [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/developer.html) for further saving to an audio file in [Matroska](https://www.matroska.org/index.html) format. But I have a problem. Since the payload of the `RTP` packet is `type 8`, I have to save the raw audio data of the [pcm_alaw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-law_algorithm) format to `mka` audio format. But when saving raw data `pcm_alaw` to an audio file, I get these messages from the library:

```cpp
...

[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time
[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time
[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time
[libopus @ 0x18eff60] Queue input is backward in time

...
```

When you open an audio file in [vlc](https://www.videolan.org/vlc/), nothing is played (the audio track timestamp is missing).

**The task of my project** is to simply take **pcm_alaw** data and **pack it in a container**, in `mka` format. The best way to determine the codec is to use the [av_guess_codec()](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/3.3/group__lavf__encoding.html#gae8a1efab53a348857f209ea51037da4c) function, which in turn automatically selects the desired codec ID. But how do I pack the raw data into the container correctly, I do not know.

**It is important to note** that I can get as raw data any format of this data (**audio formats** only) defined by the `RTP` packet type ([All](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTP_payload_formats) types of `RTP` packet payload). All I know is that in any case, **I have to pack the audio data in an `mka` container**.

I also attach the code (borrowed from [this](https://www.programmersought.com/article/2635152445/) resource) that I use:

**audiogenerater.h**

```cpp
extern "C"
{
#include "libavformat/avformat.h"
#include "libavcodec/avcodec.h"
#include "libswresample/swresample.h"
}

class AudioGenerater
{
public:

    AudioGenerater();
   ~AudioGenerater() = default;

    void generateAudioFileWithOptions(
            QString        fileName,
            QByteArray     pcmData,
            int            channel,
            int            bitRate,
            int            sampleRate,
            AVSampleFormat format);
            
private:

    // init Format
    bool initFormat(QString audioFileName);

private:

    AVCodec         *m_AudioCodec        = nullptr;
    AVCodecContext  *m_AudioCodecContext = nullptr;
    AVFormatContext *m_FormatContext     = nullptr;
    AVOutputFormat  *m_OutputFormat      = nullptr;
};
```

**audiogenerater.cpp**

```cpp
AudioGenerater::AudioGenerater()
{
    av_register_all();
    avcodec_register_all();
}

AudioGenerater::~AudioGenerater()
{
    // ... 
}

bool AudioGenerater::initFormat(QString audioFileName)
{
    // Create an output Format context
    int result = avformat_alloc_output_context2(&m_FormatContext, nullptr, nullptr, audioFileName.toLocal8Bit().data());
    if (result < 0) {
        return false;
    }

    m_OutputFormat = m_FormatContext->oformat;

    // Create an audio stream
    AVStream* audioStream = avformat_new_stream(m_FormatContext, m_AudioCodec);
    if (audioStream == nullptr) {
        avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return false;
    }

    // Set the parameters in the stream
    audioStream->id = m_FormatContext->nb_streams - 1;
    audioStream->time_base = { 1, 8000 };
    result = avcodec_parameters_from_context(audioStream->codecpar, m_AudioCodecContext);
    if (result < 0) {
        avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return false;
    }

    // Print FormatContext information
    av_dump_format(m_FormatContext, 0, audioFileName.toLocal8Bit().data(), 1);

    // Open file IO
    if (!(m_OutputFormat->flags & AVFMT_NOFILE)) {
        result = avio_open(&m_FormatContext->pb, audioFileName.toLocal8Bit().data(), AVIO_FLAG_WRITE);
        if (result < 0) {
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

void AudioGenerater::generateAudioFileWithOptions(
    QString _fileName,
    QByteArray _pcmData,
    int _channel,
    int _bitRate,
    int _sampleRate,
    AVSampleFormat _format)
{
    AVFormatContext* oc;
    if (avformat_alloc_output_context2(
            &oc, nullptr, nullptr, _fileName.toStdString().c_str())
        < 0) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }
    if (!oc) {
        printf("Could not deduce output format from file extension: using mka.\n");
        avformat_alloc_output_context2(
            &oc, nullptr, "mka", _fileName.toStdString().c_str());
    }
    if (!oc) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }
    AVOutputFormat* fmt = oc->oformat;
    if (fmt->audio_codec == AV_CODEC_ID_NONE) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }

    AVCodecID codecID = av_guess_codec(
        fmt, nullptr, _fileName.toStdString().c_str(), nullptr, AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO);
    // Find Codec
    m_AudioCodec = avcodec_find_encoder(codecID);
    if (m_AudioCodec == nullptr) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }
    // Create an encoder context
    m_AudioCodecContext = avcodec_alloc_context3(m_AudioCodec);
    if (m_AudioCodecContext == nullptr) {
        qDebug() << "Error in line: " << __LINE__;
        return;
    }

    // Setting parameters
    m_AudioCodecContext->bit_rate = _bitRate;
    m_AudioCodecContext->sample_rate = _sampleRate;
    m_AudioCodecContext->sample_fmt = _format;
    m_AudioCodecContext->channels = _channel;

    m_AudioCodecContext->channel_layout = av_get_default_channel_layout(_channel);
    m_AudioCodecContext->flags |= AV_CODEC_FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER;

    // Turn on the encoder
    int result = avcodec_open2(m_AudioCodecContext, m_AudioCodec, nullptr);
    if (result < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    // Create a package
    if (!initFormat(_fileName)) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    // write to the file header
    result = avformat_write_header(m_FormatContext, nullptr);
    if (result < 0) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    // Create Frame
    AVFrame* frame = av_frame_alloc();
    if (frame == nullptr) {
        avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
        if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
            avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
        return;
    }

    int nb_samples = 0;
    if (m_AudioCodecContext->codec->capabilities & AV_CODEC_CAP_VARIABLE_FRAME_SIZE) {
        nb_samples = 10000;
    }
    else {
        nb_samples = m_AudioCodecContext->frame_size;
    }

    // Set the parameters of the Frame
    frame->nb_samples = nb_samples;
    frame->format = m_AudioCodecContext->sample_fmt;
    frame->channel_layout = m_AudioCodecContext->channel_layout;

    // Apply for data memory
    result = av_frame_get_buffer(frame, 0);
    if (result < 0) {
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        {
            avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
            if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
                avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return;
        }
    }

    // Set the Frame to be writable
    result = av_frame_make_writable(frame);
    if (result < 0) {
        av_frame_free(&frame);
        {
            avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
            if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
                avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return;
        }
    }

    int perFrameDataSize = frame->linesize[0];
    int count = _pcmData.size() / perFrameDataSize;
    bool needAddOne = false;
    if (_pcmData.size() % perFrameDataSize != 0) {
        count++;
        needAddOne = true;
    }

    int frameCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i) {
        // Create a Packet
        AVPacket* pkt = av_packet_alloc();
        if (pkt == nullptr) {
            avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
            if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
                avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
            return;
        }
        av_init_packet(pkt);

        if (i == count - 1)
            perFrameDataSize = _pcmData.size() % perFrameDataSize;

        // Synthesize WAV files
        memset(frame->data[0], 0, perFrameDataSize);
        memcpy(frame->data[0], &(_pcmData.data()[perFrameDataSize * i]), perFrameDataSize);

        frame->pts = frameCount++;
        // send Frame
        result = avcodec_send_frame(m_AudioCodecContext, frame);
        if (result < 0)
            continue;

        // Receive the encoded Packet
        result = avcodec_receive_packet(m_AudioCodecContext, pkt);
        if (result < 0) {
            av_packet_free(&pkt);
            continue;
        }

        // write to file
        av_packet_rescale_ts(pkt, m_AudioCodecContext->time_base, m_FormatContext->streams[0]->time_base);
        pkt->stream_index = 0;
        result = av_interleaved_write_frame(m_FormatContext, pkt);
        if (result < 0)
            continue;

        av_packet_free(&pkt);
    }

    // write to the end of the file
    av_write_trailer(m_FormatContext);
    // Close file IO
    avio_closep(&m_FormatContext->pb);
    // Release Frame memory
    av_frame_free(&frame);

    avcodec_free_context(&m_AudioCodecContext);
    if (m_FormatContext != nullptr)
        avformat_free_context(m_FormatContext);
}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    av_log_set_level(AV_LOG_TRACE);

    QFile file("rawDataOfPcmAlawType.bin");
    if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
    QByteArray rawData(file.readAll());

    AudioGenerater generator;
    generator.generateAudioFileWithOptions(
               "test.mka",
               rawData,
               1, 
               64000, 
               8000,
               AV_SAMPLE_FMT_S16);

    return 0;
}
```

It is **IMPORTANT** you help me find the most appropriate way to record `pcm_alaw` or a different data format in an `MKA` audio file.

**I ask everyone who knows anything to help** (there is too little time left to implement this project)

Comment: please post the relevant code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @HassaanAli, thank you very much for your comment. The code has already been added.

Comment: From the error message I would first suspect incorrect AVPacket timestamps (check `duration`, `dts` and `pts` members to have correct values in specified time units). Also there is no need to call `av_interleaved_write_frame` (you can call just `av_write_frame`) to avoid redundant buffering if your code already guarantees that samples are written in correct oreder. Also you can try to check samples in the file with `ffprobe` utility (`ffprobe -show_frames <generated_video_file_name>`).

Comment: @Oliort, thank you very much for your comment.

In the my project, I use [this](https://github.com/momarkhan/ffmpeg_pcm_f32le_encoder/blob/master/f32le_transcode_buf.c) example. It works, but when converting f32se to mka, I get a corrupted audio track, namely, when playing audio, it runs 8 times slower. But, when dividing this string `pts += frame->nb_samples / 8;` by 8, it plays correctly. Why is this so ?

Comment: I guess that may be because of incorrect sample rate in output.

Comment: @bbdd, The problem is that you don't check for similarity between AVPacket::pts and AVPacket::dts before writing the frame to the output file (AVFormatContext).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**These useful links will help you:**

- A good overview of the data processing sequence in libav: [ffmpeg-libav-tutorial](https://github.com/leandromoreira/ffmpeg-libav-tutorial)
- Examples from the ffmpeg developers themselves: [avio_reading](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/avio_reading_8c-example.html), [resampling_audio](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/resampling_audio_8c-example.html), [transcode_aac](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcode_aac_8c-example.html)